# Kubernetes - load balance multiple services using a single load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-elb

Is it possible to load balance multiple services using a single aws load balancer? If that's not possible I guess I could just use a nodejs proxy to forward from httpd pod to tomcat pod and hope it doesn't lag...

Either way which Loadbalancer is recommended for multiport services? CLB doesn't support mutliports and ALB doesn't support mutliport for a single `/` path. So I guess NLB is the right thing implement?

I'm trying to cut cost and move to k8s but I need to know if I'm choosing the right service. Tomcat and Httpd are both part of a single prod website but can't do path based routing.

`Httpd pod service`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: httpd-service
  labels:
    app: httpd-service
  namespace: test1-web-dev
spec:
  selector:
    app: httpd
  ports:
    - name: port_80
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - name: port_443
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
    - name: port_1860
      protocol: TCP
      port: 1860
      targetPort: 1860
```

`Tomcat pod service`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tomcat-service
  labels:
    app: tomcat-service
  namespace: test1-web-dev
spec:
  selector:
    app: tomcat
  ports:
    - name: port_8080
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: port_1234
      protocol: TCP
      port: 1234
      targetPort: 1234
    - name: port_8222
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8222
      targetPort: 8222
```

Answer (score 2):

It's done like this: install `Ingress` controller (e.g. `ingress-nginx`) to your cluster, it's gonna be your loadbalancer looking into outside world.

Then configure `Ingress` resource(s) to drive traffic to services (as many as you want). Then you have a single Ingress controller (which means a single Loadbalancer) per cluster.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Comment: but ingress is based on path right? I only have one path `/` for both services and its a single site.

Comment: can you share a example? The link shows that either host or path is always different when routing to multiple services.

Comment: @John I think I missed your point... In your topology, how do you expect it to work? How ports should match? Do you want to expose 80 on http and 8080 on tomcat as the same resource? 443 + 1234, then 1860 + 8222? This is doable by using named ports, with a single LoadBalancer, without Ingress. If you confirm I'm right here, then I'm gonna update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, using Ingress controller backing with a load balancer, and use one path / you may make the Ingress tells the backing load balancer to route requests based on the Host header.

Comment: can you give me an example or a link which has example? I'm still not sure how to do that.